# Writing latex matrices from Rmarkdown to word

Tags: r, ms-word, latex, r-markdown

I'm migrating to RMarkdown provided that I work with MSWord users. 
When I try to write a matrix using latex syntaxis inside Rmarkdown using the following code:

```
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
1  & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
a_{21} & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
a_{31} & a_{32} & 1 & 0\\ 
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$
```

I obtain in Word a matrix not so well formatted. If I render a pdf the outpud works ok.

I wonder if there is a way of improving the MSWord matrix format. I supose that it must be done with pandoc or pander but I do not have expertise in this area.

Comment: When you generate a pdf, it uses LaTeX to render it. Since you have a LaTeX table, pretty result is expected. I don't know how to well format a Word table.

Comment: your code works on my machine (although I'm opening the docx with libreoffice). Could you describe precisely what is wrong in your output? What version of pandoc are you using?

Comment: The problem whith the visualization is that the squared brackets are smaller than the matrix. I tried actualizing pandoc, but it did not solve the issue.